# Visual Studio removes dll from output directory on "Start"

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have a MVVM application:

View -> ViewModel -> Model

My ViewModel is referencing a common project that has a dll with the "Build Action" set to "Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy Always":

ViewModel -> Common (dll as item)

When I clean and start my application the dll is copied to the output directory. Perfect. But when I make some modification to my code and just push the "Start" button (without cleaning), the dll is removed from the output directory.

It might not seem as a big problem, but my application is pretty big and it is just a pain having to clean/start each time I make even the smallest modification.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new solution.
2. Create three projects ("View" (WPF), "ViewModel" (class library), "Common" (class library)). There is no need to create a "Model" project for the purpose of the demonstration.
3. Create the references View -> ViewModel, ViewModel -> Common.
4. Add an arbitrary dll to the "Common" project. You can find a dll in C:\Windows\System32 if you are using Windows, or you can just create your own dll.
5. Select the dll and in the "Properties" view set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always", set the "Build Action" to "Content" if this is not default.
6. Set the "View" project as start-up project.
7. Clean the solution and press the "Start" button to build and run the project.
8. Notice the output directory now contains your arbitrary dll.
9. Now open the "MainWindow.xaml.cs" file, and add a property to the class "public int MyProperty { get; set; }" (you can make any changes to the file, the result will be the same).
10. Without cleaning press the "Start" button to build and run the modified project.
11. Notice that the dll is now removed from the output directory.

Can somebody explain why the dll is removed?

I have tried various property combinations of the dll, and experimented using the "Add as Link" instead of adding the dll the "normal" way. I have tried using different dlls to exclude the possibility that it could be that specific dll causing the problem.
And I have (of course) searched SO and googled for an answer. But only with negative results.

Any hint or idea will be appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5.

Best regards,
Casper Korshøj